# Location of specific CSS file Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm debugging an issue in Magento 2 and I'm looking for a specific CSS file. I logged the file name of the last file somewere in the Emogrifier.php and this is supposed to be the file:

`/static/version1497256942/frontend/Speak/porto/nl_NL/css/email-fonts.css`

Now, I cannot find this file anywere. I only can find the place where it's imported: `_email-extend.less` in that same Porto theme folder.

This is what that looks like: `@import url("@{baseUrl}css/email-fonts.css");`
When I go to the URL it finds that file in the static content. But I cannot find that file with that specific name anywere...

Answer (score 0):

If Magento2 has been installed via composer then you are looking for '/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/email-fonts.less' (If Magento2 has been installed from the github repository, then '/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/email-fonts.less').

Grunt converts all less files into css after the static content deployment.